# Powershell: Create LNK with Parameter

Tags: powershell, hyperlink, vbscript

I fell over this thread [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/bernhard_frank/archive/2010/03/23/shortcuts-automatisch-via-powershell-script-erzeugen.aspx) and I tried to make that a funtion to create LNK-Files to Powershell-Scripts (because I am bored to make those manually).

```
function MakeLink {
param 
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [System.String]
    $Script
)

$wshShellObject = New-Object -com WScript.Shell
$userProfileFolder = (get-childitem env:USERPROFILE).Value
$wshShellLink = $wshShellObject.CreateShortcut($userProfileFolder+"\Desktop\MeinLink.lnk") 
$wshShellLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"+$Script
$wshShellLink.WindowStyle = 1
$wshShellLink.IconLocation = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" 
$wshShellLink.WorkingDirectory = $programFilesFolder + "\Internet Explorer\" 
$wshShellLink.Save()
```

}
$Script = "C:\PowerVS\PowerVS.ps1"
MakeLink $Script

Everything works fine, exept the +$Script in line 12. The Target Path does not seems to accept any parameters (which are required for the script to work properly -.-)
I already tried to use

```
$wshShellLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" $Script
$wshShellLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe $($Script)"
```

but those did not work, either.

Has anybody an idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost as soon as I wrote this thread, I found the answer:

$wshShellLink.Arguments = $Script

Why didn't I found that one in the hours of searching before? -.-